# SSH Failed password login - log password

Tags: ssh, security, syslog

today I checked the log of my sshd and I have discovered tons of lines like :Oct 12

```
  Oct 12 12:31:34 my_user sshd[15324]: Failed password for invalid user admin from 104.194.25.135 port 2683 ssh2
Oct 12 12:31:37 my_user sshd[15324]: Failed password for invalid user admin from 104.194.25.135 port 2683 ssh2
Oct 12 12:31:39 my_user sshd[15324]: Failed password for invalid user admin from 104.194.25.135 port 2683 ssh2
Oct 12 12:31:41 my_user sshd[15324]: Failed password for invalid user admin from 104.194.25.135 port 2683 ssh2
Oct 12 12:31:45 my_user sshd[15324]: Failed password for invalid user admin from 104.194.25.135 port 2683 ssh2
Oct 12 12:31:53 my_user sshd[15326]: Failed password for invalid user admin from 104.194.25.135 port 4049 ssh2
Oct 12 12:31:55 my_user sshd[15326]: Failed password for invalid user admin from 104.194.25.135 port 4049 ssh2
Oct 12 12:31:57 my_user sshd[15326]: Failed password for invalid user admin from 104.194.25.135 port 4049 ssh2
Oct 12 12:31:59 my_user sshd[15326]: Failed password for invalid user admin from 104.194.25.135 port 4049 ssh2
Oct 12 12:32:01 my_user sshd[15326]: Failed password for invalid user admin from 104.194.25.135 port 4049 ssh2
Oct 12 12:32:04 my_user sshd[15326]: Failed password for invalid user admin from 104.194.25.135 port 4049 ssh2
Oct 12 12:32:09 my_user sshd[15329]: Failed password for invalid user admin from 104.194.25.135 port 1793 ssh2
Oct 12 12:32:12 my_user sshd[15329]: Failed password for invalid user admin from 104.194.25.135 port 1793 ssh2
Oct 12 12:32:14 my_user sshd[15329]: Failed password for invalid user admin from 104.194.25.135 port 1793 ssh2
```

I was wondering if it is possible to ask SSH to log the password they tried as well as the username.

Comment: What do you want to do with the passwords?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No openssh can't do it. You may modify sources, but usually for such studies it's useful to set up an honeypot like [kippo](https://github.com/desaster/kippo). You'll be able to watch what attacker is doing if he successfully enters your server.

You may check this good article http://www.adeptus-mechanicus.com/codex/logsshp/logsshp.html
It's about another option - use a non-standard PAM module which logs passwords.

Another great article about Python PAM module http://www.chokepoint.net/2014/01/more-fun-with-pam-python-failed.html

I ended up writing PAM module with Python just because i personally know Python. Honeypot was a little bit overkill for me.